# How to manage multiple docker files and docker-compose for local and prod setups?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently I am using docker-compose in both local and prod.
My docker-compose has volume paths that are different then in production.

My Dockerfile also is a little different between environments.

Is there a way to have different versions of each file?  How should I be naming the files to work in different environments?

If I do:

Dockerfile.local
Dockerfile.prod

How can I reference them from my docker-compose.yml file?
Can I somehow have multiple docker-compose files?

Answer (score 3):

One of the best practicies of using Docker is that you SHOULD use the exact same Dockerfile regardless of the environment.
Environment variables and cli tools such as cli should be a useful tool for covering "the gap" between each environment.

Anyway, as a workaround, docker-compose command has `-f` option which overrides a file to load. Maybe you can create `docker-compose.dev.yaml` and `docker-compose.prd.yaml` then you can use `docker-compose build -f docker-compose.dev.yaml` for dev and `docker-compose build -f docker-compose.prd.yaml`for production.